# canvas image and svg overlay

Tags: canvas, svg, d3.js, overlay, fits

I use the astrojs library (precisely [webfits](https://github.com/astrojs/webfits) and [fitsjs](https://github.com/astrojs/fitsjs)) to load a FITS file in a canvas.
I would like to add an overlay to encircle stars, trace paths and so on, and I decided to do it with [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)

This is my current test (it takes a while to download a 1MB FITS image):
http://bl.ocks.org/vertighel/raw/5193613/

[image: fits with overlay]

the drag behavior works well, but the zoom behavior is bugged. Someone know how to fix it?